# Merging Excel sheets in a workbook to make panel data table with time and firms as indices

Tags: r, excel, data-manipulation, panel-data

I want to create a panel data table for panel data regression in R. I have a workbook with each sheet containing variables for a single firm (total 5 sheets so 5 firms). The variables are same for each firm. The frequency is daily. I want a single panel data table with Firms and time as indices so that I can take yearly averages of variables for each firm and do panel data regression. I have been running the following code:

```
sheets<- c("BOB", "RIL",  "GAIL", "ITC", "MM")for (x in 1:5)  {df <- bind_rows(df, read.xlsx(path, sheet=sheets[x] ), .id= "Firm")}
```

but the above code only takes the first sheet, create Firms column with values always 1, and date column as unknown numbers. I have also tried the following code:

```
df <- bind_rows(read.xlsx(path, sheets[x]), .id= "Firm")
```

But it returns the same result. It seems that the code is able to access only the first sheet in the workbook. Please suggest a way to solve this. Following is the link to the workbook: [workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4t5SykTTU17YWdOSFlBeUljUzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Consider importing all sheets in R and transform data there. Many reshape, mutate, transpose operations are available in R. Please post sample data for reproducible example.

Comment: @Parfait I have uploaded the needed data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the `readxl` package. The `xlsx` package didn't like something in your file and threw an error.

```
library("readxl")
sheets<- c("BOB", "RIL",  "GAIL", "ITC", "MM")
df <- NULL
for (sheet in sheets){
  tmp <- read_excel(path, sheet=paste0(sheet, " IS Equity"))
  tmp$firm <- rep(sheet, nrow(tmp))
  df <- rbind(df, tmp)
}
```

Comment: I suspect your sheets are not of identical format. Column names and data types should be the same. I'll edit my code to add an id column.

Comment: I can't help any more without a file to test on.

Comment: I've edited my answer. `xlsx` package didn't like your file. the `readxl` package worked fine.

Comment: Thank you, @cory. People like you make this site a wonderful place.

Comment: the `sheet` argument can take an index or a sheet name. So you can say `for(sheet in 1:500){ ... ` and `read_excel(path, sheet=sheet)`

Comment: `df <- df[,c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]`

Comment: Based on your suggestions, I have this code: df <- NULL
for (sheet in excel_sheets(path)){
    tmp <- read_excel(path, sheet=sheet)
    tmp$id <- rep(sheet, nrow(tmp))
    df <- rbind(df, tmp)
}
df <- df[,c(ncol(df), 1:(ncol(df)-1))]   . please update so others can use it directly as a function for creating panel data table from a workbook containing mant sheets.